# Missing required parameters for [Route: messenger.store]

Tags: laravel

Why it gives an error of undefined id, i just changed Route::get to route::post and it says that id is undefined... should i change the way i pass it? is it a correct way of inserting data into database ?

here's the route

```
Route::post('messenger/store/{id}','MessengerController@store')->name('messenger.store');
```

View...

```
{!! Form::open(['method'=>'POST','action'=>['MessengerController@store',$id]]) !!}

    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::text('msg',null,['class'=>'form-control'])!!}
        </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::submit('Send Message',['class'=>'btn btn-primary'])!!}
    </div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

index controller from where i pass ID

```
public function index($id)
{
    //
    $user=Auth::user();
    return view('messenger.index',compact('user','id'));
}
```

Comment: How you display view?

Comment: How `$id` comes here `['MessengerController@store',$id]` ?

Comment: it's passed from index controller

Comment: Share that code I guess you are not getting value for `$id`

Comment: index($id){
return view with id
}

Comment: Share exact code this is not you controllers code

Comment: is it enough?  i'll add as much as u want, it's just i don't want to add unnececcary code

Comment: Just set default value as `1` and share what happen here `index($id=1)`

Comment: still the same,here's full error
"Missing required parameters for [Route: messenger.store] [URI: messenger/store/{id}]. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\resources\views\messenger\index.blade.php)"

Comment: Add `@csrf` token inside form

Comment: still the same, this problem occured since i changed Route::get to Route::post

Comment: I guess you getting because you are not getting $id , you can check `$id ?? 1` to make default as `1`

Comment: i guess it doesn't get $id, since it's Post.

Comment: How you are calling `MessengerController@index` ?

Comment: simple Route::get('messenger/{id}','MessengerController@index'); 
i guess Route::resource is only solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{!! Form::open(['method'=>'POST','action'=>['MessengerController@store',$id]]) !!}

    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::text('msg',null,['class'=>'form-control'])!!}
        </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::submit('Send Message',['class'=>'btn btn-primary'])!!}
    </div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

change this.

```
{!! Form::open(['method'=>'POST','url'=>route('messenger.store',[$id])]) !!}

    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::text('msg',null,['class'=>'form-control'])!!}
        </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::submit('Send Message',['class'=>'btn btn-primary'])!!}
    </div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

to this.

Using `action` is kind of deprecated.

Comment: Works... Thanks for the tip!!